# Orthornormal bases of H weakly converges to zero

Tags: functional-analysis

[img]https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7ZZc.png

I understand convergence of a sequence in general. However can anyone explain what it means for a sequence to converge weakly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weak convergence means convergence in the [weak topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_topology). It is the coarsest topology (meaning the topology with fewest open sets) that makes the bounded linear functionals continuous. The usual subbasis for this topology is given by sets of the form $f^{-1}(a, \infty)$ (or indeed, $f^{-1}(\mathcal{U})$ where $\mathcal{U}$ is open in the scalar field). As usual we form a basis by finite intersection of these sets.

A sequence $x_n$ converges to $x$ in the weak topology if and only if $f(x_n) \to f(x)$ for all bounded linear functionals $f$ in the dual space.

In a Hilbert space, the bounded linear functionals (by the Riesz Representation Theorem) must take the form $\langle \cdot, u \rangle$ for some $u \in H$. So, as per your solution, we have $x_n$ weakly converges to $0$ if and only if
$$\langle x_n, u \rangle \to \langle 0, u \rangle = 0$$
for all $u \in H$.